# When holomorphic convexity implies polynomial convexity

Tags: cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

For what follows I refer to Forstneric's Book "Stein Manifolds and Holomorphic mappings", Theorem 4.14.6 p. 168 (second edition).

I need some clarifications.

It starts talking about a complex curve $X$ in $\Bbb C^n$. I assume he means a $1$-dim complex manifold with smooth boundary.
It is assumed that the boundary is composed by a finite number of unbounded smooth curves.

The proof starts by considering a normal exhaustion of $X$ by holomorphically convex compacts, that is
$$
K_1\subset K_2\subset\cdots\subset\bigcup_{j\ge1}K_j=X
$$
where $K_j$ is $\mathcal O(X)$-convex, that is
$$
\widehat {K_j}_{\mathcal O(X)}:=\{z\in X\;:\;|f(z)|\le\|f\|_{K_j}\;\forall f\in\mathcal O(X)\}=K_j\;.
$$

> **Question 1.** Why does such an exhaustion exist? I know that this is the case if $X$ is holomorphically convex, but why $X$ should be such?

Then we have to prove that every $K\subset X$ which is $\mathcal O(X)$-convex with smooth boundary, is polynomially convex too, that is $\widehat K:=\{z\in \Bbb C^n\;:\;|f(z)|\le\|f\|_{K}\;\forall f\in\mathcal O(\Bbb C^n)\}=K$ (this would allow us to achieve that the above exhaustion is actually made of polynomially convex sets, not just $\mathcal O(X)$-convex).

It starts by considering that $\widehat K=\widehat {\partial K}$ (from max. princ.) and then define
$$
A=\widehat K\setminus\partial K
$$
which is an analytic set (it is a result by Stolzenberg) in $\Bbb C^n\setminus\partial K$. Then argues by contradiction: if $A\neq K\setminus\partial K$, then $A$ should share "some piece" with an unbounded component of $X\setminus K$, then (by a result in Chirca's "Complex Analytic Sets", uniqueness thm pag 62) a component $Y$ of $A$ different than $K\setminus\partial K$ must coincide with the components of $X\setminus K$ intersected by $A$. But the components of $X\setminus K$ are unbounded hence $A$ is unbounded, contradiction.

> **Question 2.** Why? I cannot see this at all.

For the uniqueness theorem to apply, we need $X\setminus K$ to be an analytic set: why is this true? And in general, all the contradiction argument is totally obscure (which are the last three lines in proving (1) in Forstneric's book).

Comment: Regarding your Q1, take any compact exhaustion $(L_j)$ of $X$ and define $K_1:=\widehat{L_1}_{\mathcal{O}(X)}$. Since $K_1$ is compact you can find $j_2>1$ such that $K_1\subset$ int$L_{j_2}$. Now define $K_2:=\widehat{L_{j_2}}_{\mathcal{O}(X)}$ and continue this procedure. The sets $K_j$ are clearly holomorphically convex.

Comment: Regarding Q2 please be more specific and indicate which step of the proof you have troubles understanding.

Comment: Thanks for Q1. Regarding Q2: I don't understand why in this setting, a $\mathcal O(X)$-convex set is also polynomially convex. In my question I have outlined the detail in the proof of this claim I don't understand: it starts by considering $A=\widehat K\setminus\partial K$, pointing out some features of this object and then arguing by contradiction. I have written it in detail.

Comment: Did you look at the original proof in [Wold, E.F.: Embedding Riemann surfaces properly into C2. Int. J. Math. 17(8), 963–974], see Proposition 3.1. It seems to me that it containes much more details. In there you can assume that $K=\emptyset$, and you should be able to conclude that the the sets $K_j$ in the exaustion are polynomially convex. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I looked at that paper. The proof presented there is more general, and I was wondering how can such a proof compressed in just 3 lines by Forstneric. This is what I don't understand and I would like to.

Comment: "... I was wondering how can such a proof compressed in just 3 lines..." easy by skipping many details, which are not-trival to a non-specialists (the proof is just a compressed version of the original using the same arguments). In this paricular case I think it is better to follow Wold's proof of Proposition 3.1 were you should assume that $K=\emptyset$.